# Class attribute issue

Tags: python

I have two classes and one class has an attribute that is an instance of the second class. In the second class I have a parameter that takes in an arbitrary amount of arguments thus not needing to take in any. However if I call my attribute that is an instance of the class, how can I pass an argument into the class while calling the attribute so as to add an argument.

Please see my code below, I am talking about the self.privileges attribute under Admin that is an instance of the Privileges() class.

```
"""A class used to represent the admin of a website"""

from user import User

class Privileges():
    """A class to show and descrive the privileges of the Admin"""

    def __init__(self, *privileges):
        """Show the available privileges"""
        self.privileges = ('can add post', 'can delete post', 'can ban user',
            'can override', 'can accept user') + privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        """Show the admin his list of privileges"""
        print("The Admin has the following list of privileges:")
        for privileges in self.privileges:
            print(f"-{privileges}")

class Admin(User):
    """Subclass to the parent user class"""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, gender):
        """Initialize attributes from the parent class"""
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, gender)
        self.privileges = Privileges()


    def greet_user(self):
        """Re-writing greet user method for the admin"""
        print("Hello Admin")
```

Comment: The question you are asking is unclear

Comment: Basically if I want to call admin.privileges but I want to add an argument to the tuple how do i do that

Comment: Question is unclear, but your instantiation of Privileges() appears to require a set of args.  If you try `self.privileges = Privileges` without the parentheses, then it should be okay, but it won't be instantiated.

Comment: sorry and admin is an instance I created

Comment: so i did admin = Admin(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ')

Comment: then I wanted to call admin.privileges and add an argument to that attribute i hope that makes more sense

Comment: It looks like you want to have an `add_privilege` method in the `Privilege` class.  It wouldn't make sense to try to do this with the `__init__` method after the object has been constructed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, you could add `privileges` as an argument to the `Admin` constructor and then pass it through to the `Privileges` constructor:

```
class Admin(User):
    """Subclass to the parent user class"""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, gender, privileges):
        """Initialize attributes from the parent class"""
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, gender)
        self.privileges = Privileges(*privileges)
```

Another option is to add a method on `Admin` that updates the privileges:

```
class Admin(User):
    """Subclass to the parent user class"""

    # constructor etc.

    def set_privileges(self, *privileges):
        self.privileges = Privileges(*privileges)
```

Comment: so lets say I create an admin instance, admin = Admin('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') and then I want to call the attribute admin.privileges but i realized I want to add another argument to the tuple associated with the class Privileges is there a way to do it through the call

Comment: @DennisSparrow I considered that but being unnamed arguments I thought that having to pass a list of privileges was a bit easier to understand than just having an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: @Duke3e33 Then you could add an `add_privelege` method to the `Privileges` class and call `admin.privileges.add_privelege`.

Comment: @DanielGibbs, sorry, I deleted the comment to which you responded, because Duke3e33 didn't seem to want to do it in the constructor, which you addressed in your following comment, which matched what I posted as a comment on the question.